# Why the XCode 6 test Navigator does not use XCTest but SenTestingKit?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

Any Test class I create from the Tests Navigator (the plus (+) button on the left bottom), it add:
 `#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>` instead of XCTest.

- This is my Xcode version: Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Note: This is an existing project, old ones which I recently updated to use ARC instead of MRC, it is up and running and GHUnit (https://github.com/gh-unit/gh-unit) was working on it,
I've removed GHUnit in order to use XCTest.

These are the steps:

1. From the project navigator I click the + button to add a "New Test Class".
   [image]
2. I set the Class name...
   [image]
3. Set where the class will be saved...
   [image]
4. The file is created, however instead of import XCTest it does import SenTestKit =(
   [image]

   - However it creates properly if I create the class using: File > New > File then select "Test Case Class" click "Next" set the class name, the screen is different,
     it show a "Subclass of" dropdown and XCTestCase is selected on it:
     [image]
   - Then the XCTest class is created properly:
     [image]

This what I did trying to solve the issue:

- Did check if the test bundle "Wrapper Extension" was set to xctest (yeah it is)
- Reinstalled my Xcode
- Took the opportunity to upgrade to Yosemite =D

Did not solve the issue.
This happens even if I create a new project :(

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I did contact Apple and looks likes this is a bug on XCode.

You can see the thread here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1094651#1094651

Also, these steps can be used as an workaround:

File > New > File then select "Test Case Class" click "Next" set the class name.

The Test Class will be created properly.

I will post more details here once the Apple people update the bug I did report.